# Error downloading YouTube-8M dataset with curl in Windows 8.1

Tags: youtube, deep-learning, kaggle

I'm trying to download a small chunk of the YouTube-8M dataset. It is just a dataset with video features and labels and you can create your own model to classify them.

The command that they claim will download the dataset is this :

```
curl storage.googleapis.com/data.yt8m.org/download_fix.py | shard=1,100 partition=2/frame/train mirror=us python
```

This actually didn't worked at all and the error produced is :

```
'shard' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or bash file.
```

I found someone posted on a forum. It says to add 'set' to the variables which seems to fix my problem partially.

```
curl storage.googleapis.com/data.yt8m.org/download_fix.py | set shard=1,100 partition=2/video/train mirror=us python
```

The download seemingly started for a split second and an error pop up. The error right now is `(23) Failed writing body`.

[image]

So what is the command line for downloading the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using the Kaggle API instead. You can install the API using:

```
pip install Kaggle
```

Then download your credentials ([step-by-step guide here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/upload-update-data-kaggle-api/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1)). Finally, you can download the dataset like so:

```
kaggle competitions download -c youtube8m
```

If you only want part of the dataset, you can first list all the downloadable files:

```
kaggle competitions files -c youtube8m
```

And then only download the file(s) you want:

```
kaggle competitions download -c youtube8m -f name_of_your_file.extension
```

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Are you on a linux machine?

Comment: Are you on a linux machine?

Comment: yes, but the API syntax (except for things like file paths) should be the same across different OS's